# How to initialize Cipher variable with mod and exp of public key

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, encryption

I have a custom public key class that generates mod and exp explicitly instead of using the publickey from the java.security. Now how do I initialize the cipher variable for encryption with the mod and exp that I have .

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
String mod = pbkey.getMod();
String exp = pbkey.getExp();
```

How to achieve equivalent of

```
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, java.security.PublicKeyVariable);
```

using the mod and exp?

thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a [`RSAPublicKeySpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPublicKeySpec.html), pass it to [`KeyFactory.generatePublic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html), then pass the result as the second argument to `cipher.init`.  See [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm).